# Can I change the type of the accumulator on the .reduce method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typescript, reduce

I'm currently trying to reduce a string into number[], but I'm new to typescript and simply couldn't figure out how to type my code so that the typescript compiler would stop complaining...

What I'm trying to do:

```
matString.split(/[\n ]/).reduce((acc, cur, index) => acc[index] = Number(cur));
```

So far, I have tried typing it like this, but it just won't work :(

```
matString.split(/[\n ]/).reduce((acc: Array<number>, cur, index) => acc[index] = Number(cur)) as Array<number>;
```

Just for context, this code is receiving a matrix in the format of a string and I want to convert it down to an array so that I can work with it. I have already encountered this issue under different circumstances and had to work around it, but this time I would like to understand how to fix it.

Also, if it does help explain my issue better, here's a picture of my code followed by the compiler's error: [code image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXQAx.png)

This is part of my solution to [this](https://exercism.org/tracks/typescript/exercises/matrix) exercise on [exercism](https://exercism.org).

Comment: First of all, you're missing the initial value. What should `reduce` return if the array is empty?

Comment: keep in mind that you can't split a number into it's digits without turning it back into a string. The excercise you link to doesn't mention types, only that you should be able to access each character in the string as an element of the matrix, so perhaps focus on the *shape* of the array to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

While it's *possible*, it'd be far easier to avoid `.reduce` and just map the split string to `Number`, no explicit typing necessary:

```
const result = matString
  .split(/[\n ]/)
  .map(Number);
```

If you had to go the `.reduce` route, use generics to indicate the accumulator type, and remember to return the accumulator at the end of the callback:

```
const result = matString.split(/[\n ]/).reduce<Array<number>>((acc, cur, index) => {
    acc[index] = Number(cur);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

If the input is composed of a string that contains numeric characters, it might be better to match those characters, instead of splitting on newlines and spaces:

```
const result = matString
  .match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g) // assuming there will always be at least one match
  .map(Number);
```

Comment: Thank you! That solves my issue and I have now learned how to work my way around these kinds of warnings from typescript :)

Comment: Also, I need to separate the rows and columns of the matrix coming into that string trough the \n characters, representing the end of rows. Still thinking about how to do that, but dismantling the string like this seemed like a logical step to begin with.

Comment: If each line is guaranteed to contain something you want to parse, split on newlines, then map each line to the parsed structure you want. `.split('\n').map(line => line.match(/\d+/g).map(Number))` or something like that